# Sony 50mm 1.2 GM lens has loose elements inside?

Tags: sony, 50mm

I just received my Sony 50mm f1.2 lens. When holding the lens by itself, if I turn it over front on top, then back on top, and repeat, there are elements inside that shift around. They feel heavy, so may be glass.

For those that have this lens, is this normal?

Comment: Do we talk about Sony FE 50mm f/1.2 GM?

Comment: Yes. I believe there is only one Sony 50mm 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

As this lens have no image stabilization the only moving element inside can be focusing element/group (if the lens is not broken of course). And it is normal to be heavy, this is 1.2 lens.

Comment: Do you have this lens and does yours do the same thing ?

Comment: @Roxy, no, I do not have it. Just common sense.